# Position QCheckBox top left of item in QListView

Tags: python, pyside

How can i position the Checkbox of an item in a QListView at the top left? I tried using a stylesheet but when i resize my item, the checkbox does not maintain it's position in the top left. It becomes hidden.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Do I use QItemDelegate or QStyledItemDelegate to solve my problem?

My goal is to make it appear like this...

[image]

```
import os, sys, re
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PictureShop.Resources import StyleUtils


################################################################################
# Dummy Values
################################################################################
values = ['MomBod','Colonel','Tater','Tot','Ginger','Donut','Sport','LaLa','Itchy','Bruiser','Cotton','Cumulus','Toodles']


################################################################################
# Widgets
################################################################################
class ViewerWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(500,500)

        self.uiIconSize = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.uiIconSize.setRange(32,256)
        self.uiIconSize.setValue(96)
        self.uiIconSize.setMinimumWidth(100)

        self.viewerModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.uiListView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.uiListView.setSpacing(5)
        self.uiListView.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.uiListView.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.uiListView.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Batched)
        self.uiListView.setBatchSize(100)
        self.uiListView.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.uiListView.setWrapping(True)
        self.uiListView.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.uiListView.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.uiListView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.uiListView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiListView.setModel(self.viewerModel)

        # layout
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiListView)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiIconSize)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Signals
        self.uiIconSize.valueChanged.connect(self.slotChangedIconSize)
        self.uiIconSize.setValue(96)
        self.uiListView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(96,96))

        # Init
        self.populateModel()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget::indicator {
                subcontrol-position: top center;
                position: relative;
                left: 30px;
                top: -20px;
            }

        ''')


    # Methods
    def populateModel(self):
        model = self.viewerModel
        model.clear()

        icon = QtGui.QIcon('C:/Users/jmartini/Desktop/brokenImage.png')
        for x in values:
            newItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            newItem.setCheckable(True)
            newItem.setData(icon, role=QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
            model.appendRow(newItem)


    # Slots
    def slotChangedIconSize(self):
        size = self.uiIconSize.value()
        self.uiListView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(size,size))


################################################################################
# Unit Testing
################################################################################
def test_ViewerWidget():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setOrganizationName('mine')
    app.setApplicationName('browser')
    ex = ViewerWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    test_ViewerWidget()
```

Help from answers below. I have a bug shown here:

[image]

Got a working solution based on comments below:

```
import os, sys, re
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


################################################################################
# Dummy Values
################################################################################
values = ['MomBod','Colonel','Tater','Tot','Ginger','Donut','Sport','LaLa','Itchy','Bruiser','Cotton','Cumulus','Toodles']



class ItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)


    # overrides
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        isw, ish = option.decorationSize.toTuple()
        return QtCore.QSize(isw, ish)


    def getCheckboxRect(self, option):
        return QtCore.QRect(4, 4, 18, 18).translated(option.rect.topLeft())


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        # Draw
        isw, ish = option.decorationSize.toTuple()
        x, y, dx, dy = option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), option.rect.width(), option.rect.height()

        # Decoration
        pic = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        if pic:
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, pic.pixmap(isw, ish))

        # Indicate Selected
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,70,240,128)))
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))
        painter.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(x, y, dx, dy))

        # Checkstate
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if value is not None:
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem()
            opt.rect = self.getCheckboxRect(option)
            opt.state = opt.state & ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus
            if value == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
            elif value == QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked:
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_NoChange
            elif value == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                opt.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
            style.drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck, opt, painter, None
            )

        painter.restore()


    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        flags = model.flags(index)
        if (
            not (flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            or not (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled)
            or not (flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        ):
            return False

        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if value is None:
            return False

        style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        if event.type() in (
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
        ):
            viewOpt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            self.initStyleOption(viewOpt, index)
            checkRect = self.getCheckboxRect(viewOpt)
            if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton or not checkRect.contains(
                event.pos()
            ):
                return False
            if event.type() in (
                QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
                QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            ):
                return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() not in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Space, QtCore.Qt.Key_Select):
                return False
        else:
            return False
        state = value
        if flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate:
            state = QtCore.Qt.CheckState((state + 1) % 3)
        else:
            state = (
                QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked else QtCore.Qt.Checked
            )
        return model.setData(index, state, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)

################################################################################
# Widgets
################################################################################
class ViewerWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(500,500)

        self.uiIconSize = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.uiIconSize.setRange(32,256)
        self.uiIconSize.setValue(96)
        self.uiIconSize.setMinimumWidth(100)

        self.viewerModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.uiListView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.uiListView.setSpacing(5)
        self.uiListView.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.uiListView.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.uiListView.setLayoutMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Batched)
        self.uiListView.setBatchSize(100)
        self.uiListView.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.uiListView.setWrapping(True)
        self.uiListView.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.uiListView.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.uiListView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.uiListView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiListView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiListView.setModel(self.viewerModel)
        self.uiListView.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate())

        # layout
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiListView)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiIconSize)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Signals
        self.uiIconSize.valueChanged.connect(self.slotChangedIconSize)
        self.uiIconSize.setValue(96)
        self.uiListView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(96,96))

        # Init
        self.populateModel()


    # Methods
    def populateModel(self):
        model = self.viewerModel
        model.clear()



        icon = QtGui.QIcon("C:/Users/JokerMartini-Asus/Desktop/thumbnail_image.png")
        for x in values:
            newItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            newItem.setCheckable(True)
            newItem.setData(icon, role=QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
            model.appendRow(newItem)


    # Slots
    def slotChangedIconSize(self):
        size = self.uiIconSize.value()
        self.uiListView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(size,size))


################################################################################
# Unit Testing
################################################################################
def test_ViewerWidget():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setOrganizationName('mine')
    app.setApplicationName('browser')
    ex = ViewerWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    test_ViewerWidget()
```

Comment: publish your edition as an answer :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc I will do that once i figure out how to get the style of the qcheckbox to match the style of the application. It doesn't appear to look like the normal checkbox in pyside for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using a delegate you can paint after the icon is painted:

```
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(Delegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.features &= ~QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasCheckIndicator

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(Delegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if value is not None:
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem()
            opt.rect = self.checkRect(option)
            opt.state = opt.state & ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus
            if value == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
            elif value == QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked:
                opt.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_NoChange
            elif value == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                opt.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            widget = option.widget
            style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style() if widget is None else widget.style()
            style.drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck, opt, painter, widget
            )

    def checkRect(self, option):
        height = option.rect.height()
        x, y, w, h = (f * height for f in (0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2))
        return QtCore.QRect(x, y, w, h).translated(option.rect.topLeft())

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        # https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp?h=5.13#n278
        flags = model.flags(index)
        if (
            not (flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            or not (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled)
            or not (flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        ):
            return False
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if value is None:
            return False
        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style() if widget is not None else QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        if event.type() in (
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
        ):
            viewOpt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            self.initStyleOption(viewOpt, index)
            checkRect = self.checkRect(viewOpt)
            if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton or not checkRect.contains(
                event.pos()
            ):
                return False
            if event.type() in (
                QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
                QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
            ):
                return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() not in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Space, QtCore.Qt.Key_Select):
                return False
        else:
            return False
        state = value
        if flags & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserTristate:
            state = QtCore.Qt.CheckState((state + 1) % 3)

        else:
            state = (
                QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked else QtCore.Qt.Checked
            )
        return model.setData(index, state, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

Comment: Whats the missing value here `line 14, in initStyleOption
    super(self).initStyleOption(option, index)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not ItemDelegate`

Comment: @JokerMartini Already update it, you should use the python2.7 tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Im sorry i didn't specify. I  should have done that. As your update helped fix it but now i get this error `line 14, in initStyleOption
    option.features &= ~QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasCheckIndicator
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem' object has no attribute 'features'`

Comment: @JokerMartini I have tested it with PySide2/PyQt5 since I don't have PySide at hand, so I will need your help to correct the differences in the versions.

Comment: I'm using the latest of PySide 1.2.4 on windows. I get this error that option does not have property widget. `AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Comment: @JokerMartini change `widget = option.widget` to `widget = None`

Comment: @JokerMartini and try adding `option = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)` before `option.features &= ~QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasCheckIndicator`

Comment: @JokerMartini If it does not work then I will have to install pyside on my PC to find an alternative but this unfortunately will not be soon

Comment: I emailed you the screenshot

Comment: Can someone provide a C++ example of this?